# I run an adult website from a Muslim country where they are illegal, how do I avoid using my real name with domain name registration?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, whois, private-registration

I live in Muslim country where adults sites are banned. I do have such website hosted in US but registrar is asking for real info now.

I do have Private Registration (Whois Guard at Namecheap) enabled. Meaning public can't see my real info. Should i stop worrying after enabling Whois Guard and entering my real info to registrar. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Is the domain registrar also in the US (or another country outside of your own)?

Answer (score 1):

The main reason behind asking for real info is so that in rare cases of an ownership dispute you can prove with authority that you are indeed the owner of a certain domain. Also, ICANN requires you to put in accurate info and if someone 'complains' or does some other unlikely event, you can lose your domain without any recourse.

Many questionable / black hat SEO companies have no issue whatsoever putting in erroneous info into that registration info field. Putting in inaccurate info is probably not a good idea in general, violates the terms and conditions of the registrar and would cripple your ability to prove ownership in an ownership dispute, but in reality, most all of these concerns and downsides will never be experienced in many cases.